# How to run Ansible playbook with user input within Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have a playbook with section "pause" and prompt. If I create job within Jenkins with Pipeline plugin and run this job I get

```
[WARNING]: Not waiting from prompt as stdin is not interactive
```

and job is failed. The question is how I can run job in interactive mode or how I can pause playbook within exact task and push combination Ctrl+c+c (because ansible module '`pause`' is working only like that)? I have googled a few time and tried to do that with

```
def userInput = input(
    id: 'Password', message: 'input your input: ', ok: 'ok',
    parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '.....', name: 'INPUT_TEST')])
```

But I can't push keys combination and can't understand how I can pause jenkins job on specific ansible task within playbook.

Pipeline example:

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
  environment {
  WORKDIR = '/home/jenkins/'
  }
  stages {

  stage('Checkout') {
    agent { label 'master' }
    steps {
      sh '''cd $WORKDIR
      ansible-playbook -vvvv manual_playbooks/test.yml'''
      }
    }  

  stage ('Echo') {
     agent { label 'master' }
     steps {
        sh 'echo something' 
     }
  }
  }
}
```

Playbook example:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Echo start
      shell: echo 'start playbook'

    - pause:
        prompt: "do you want to continue?"
        echo: yes
        private: no
      register: prompt_status

    - name: Continue tasks
      shell: echo 'Continue full flow'
      register: reset_account_response
      when: prompt_status.user_input is defined and 
            prompt_status.user_input == "yes"

    - fail:
        msg: "Unexpected user input while prompting approval"
      when: prompt_status.user_input is defined and 
            prompt_status.user_input != "yes"
```

Many thanks.

Comment: possibly question already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382164/how-do-i-script-a-yes-response-for-installing-programs-in-ansible

Comment: Having prompt and interactive input in script environment is a non-sense when you run in Jenkins or automated way. What the point to have that ? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Actually not. I've clarified that needs to push combination Ctrl+c+c in exact task.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a when clause on your pause task to check for the existence of some other variable and then pass that in using Ansible's -e option when running the playbook through Jenkins.

Comment: -e options are not secure. Their content is readable for example using ps aux, so they are not suitable for passing secrets.